# PayPal & Google Analytics ecommerce Integration

Tags: google-analytics, paypal, paypal-ipn, google-analytics-api

I am trying to integrate PayPal with Google Analytics ecommerce tracking using PayPal IPN API.
I know there are few questions here on SO similar however none is answering my query.

I am using PayPal Buy Now buttons so the customers are leaving the main site and the purchase is happening on PayPal site.

The PayPal IPN listener part is already written in PHP and I think is OK. I can also send the PayPal data as a transaction in GA using the GA API (_addtrans, _additem and _tracktrans). This is not a problem.

What I am not able to figure out is how to link the initial GA user data ([where they came from, what they clicked etc]) with the particular PayPal purchase (remember the purchase itself is happening on PayPal site and not on the main site).

I found this link in which a solution is suggested however there are no specific details about how this might be implemented in a PHP/JavaScript script.

http://marketlytics.com/blog/accurately-integrate-paypal-with-google-analytics-ecommerce/

Basically, the question is, **how the following words can be mapped to a PHP/Javascript script?**

> To make this work we started with identifying a user when they leave for paypal to make > a purchase. This is essential because we need to be able to connect a user’s initial >behavior [where they came from, what they clicked etc] with the final purchase. Because >the user may or may not come back its essential to have a way to identify users.
>
> Second we configured IPN to send alerts whenever a transaction was completed. Using the > information from the transaction and the unique identifier we configured in the first we > had all the data we needed to tell Google Analytics about the order.